# Calender as drop down list

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody tell me the meaning of

```
ew:CalendarPopup ID="ucCalendar" runat="server" Width="80px" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif"
                                    ControlDisplay="LabelImage" ShowGoToToday="True" CalendarLocation="Bottom" UseExternalResource="True"
                                    ExternalResourcePath="~/Include/JS/Calendar/eWorld_UI_CalendarPopup.js" Nullable="True"
                                    ToolTip="Select meeting date">
                                    <WeekdayStyle Font-Size="XX-Small" Font-Names="Verdana,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial" ForeColor="Black"
                                        BackColor="White"></WeekdayStyle>
```

Pls its urgent

Comment: what meaning. you area using custom control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses a server control called [`CalendarPopup`](http://www.eworldui.net/CustomControls/CalendarPopup.aspx) declared by the `ew` TagPrefix in the [@Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx) directive or in web.config. It also initializes some of its properties.